# SVG AnyElement.remove()

Tags: javascript, svg

What is the cross browser compatible alternative to someElmntInSVGDom.remove()?
It seem that it is not working except in Chrome.

I am looking not for library functions but for a way to do it in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someElmntInSVGDom.parentNode.removeChild(someElmntInSVGDom) should do it.
```

Documentation here [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why did they specify not .remove()?